# deselect Doo tab bar button

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

After pressing on tabBar Button

```
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" class="tab_bar"
            data-dojo-props='fixed: "bottom"' >

            <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton"
                onclick="function()"
                data-dojo-props='icon1:"images/carrello.png", icon2:"images/raccolta_ordini.png"'>Aggiungi</li>

        </ul>
```

the button remains selected (see the picture before-after)
[image]
which statement should I use, in the function, to unselect the button?

Answer (score 1):

Assign an id to button (id_button) and write this

```
    id_button.setAttribute("class","mblTabBarButton mblTabBarButtonHasIcon")
```

with this istruction you change a button css class.

Comment: works for a few tenths of a second (see it with debugger),when It get out of from  function where is the instruction, the button is selected again